# How do I use the IncludeXmlComments to point to my second project in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

So I have a solution with two projects, the main project being `MultipleProjectsSwaggerDocs` and then `Public` which I added as a reference to the main project. Both of these are `ASP.NET Web API (.NET 6)` and I have the main project as the startup project.

I'm trying to setup Swagger so that xml comments that are above the function show in the UI, for instance.
[image]

I've actually managed to get it to work by following the guide over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).
I then noticed that it wouldn't show xml comments that I added to `Public`, it would only show the comments that were in the`MultipleProjectsSwaggerDocs` project.

So after looking around for a while, I noticed that I could just add another `options.IncludeXmlComments(...)` and the only problem with that is that I need to hardcode the path to the file that's generated in the other project.

That won't work if I were to host the project.

Here is what the `Program.cs` looks like for the main project `MultipleProjectsSwaggerDocs`

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "ToDo API",
        Description = "An ASP.NET Core Web API for managing ToDo items",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        {
            Name = "Example Contact",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/contact")
        },
        License = new OpenApiLicense
        {
            Name = "Example License",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license")
        }
    });

    
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));

    /* Issue */
    options.IncludeXmlComments(@"C:\Users\HomePC\source\repos\MultipleProjectsSwaggerDocs\Public\bin\Debug\net6.0\Public.xml");
});
```

As of right now, that works great, it shows the docs for each endpoint.
[image]

But as you can see, the path to the other xml file is hardcoded, and that's not good if I were to host the project, because it wouldn't find the file. Is there something I can do in order to point it to the second project?

And if this is not the correct way to setup `AddSwaggerGen` with two projects in one solution, then what is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, it is not necessary to hardcode the full path to the second xml comments file. When you connected the first file, you wrote `Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename)`. Nobody forbids you to do the same with the second :)

For example, I usually use the following code to connect my xml comments to Swagger:

```
string[] allMyXmlCommentFileNames =
{
    $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml",
    "Public.xml"
};
foreach (string fileName in allMyXmlCommentFileNames)
{
    string xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, fileName);
    if (File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
        options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlFilePath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
}
```

---

### Some theory why this should work

For example, if you open the `Public\Public.csproj` file, then in my case Rider will generate the following code for me in this file if I add xml comment generation to this project:

```
<DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\net6.0\Public.xml</DocumentationFile>
```

And when you build a .NET project, all projects linked to it are added as separate dlls to the `bin\Debug\net6.0` folder of the project you are building. And it works for xml comments too, they will be there too.

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea it actually added the `Public.xml` file to the same bin folder! Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @JohnA A good solution is always simple. Always happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "ToDo API",
        Description = "An ASP.NET Core Web API for managing ToDo items",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        {
            Name = "Example Contact",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/contact")
        },
        License = new OpenApiLicense
        {
            Name = "Example License",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license")
        }
    });
    foreach (var filePath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)!), "*.xml"))
    {
        try
        {
            options.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }


});
```